# how to register objects or collections for importing using python script

Tags: python, scripting, import

i have a template for a add on, that includes the code for importing assets. my question is how do i link my objects or collection to the code so they will import. i'm a beginner to this so any helps is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, could you share a bit of your code or explain more in depth your end goal ?

Comment: hi so basically i am creating a asset pack, and i would like to create a add on that imports or appends the models into the scene. I've found a template that includes the import code, but i need to somehow connect the assets so the code knows what to import